# How to dynamically change Interface Builder xib files by writing Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder, xib

Today I'm writing my first "Hello World" application for iOS. And I wondered how can I manipulate `.xib` files programmatically similar to Android `XML` layout files or `XAML`? I also want Interface Builder dynamically display changes. For example I have a `.xib` file `"LoginPageView.xib"`, where I have buttons and other controls which I added via `Interface Builder` constructor, then I connect this `.xib` to the private `class extension` of `"LoginPageViewController"` in `.m` file. And now I want to add a new button programmatically: `UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithCGRect:...];` or I want to change button's background and so on.

The only way I know is to implement it in `viewDidLoad` method but if I do this my changes will display only when program run and I want Interface Builder dynamically display these changes before compiling. So the question is there some way in Xcode IDE to implement this and instructions how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is no, this is not possible. The long answer is that you could possibly implement such a thing by reverse engineering the .xib file format (which is XML), and figuring out how to write it yourself. It would be far more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but wouldn't any attemps at XML manipulation prove frivolous once the xibs were compiled to nibs?

Comment: Actually, @NSPostWhenIdle, I wrote a XIB XML reader.  Not much is actually gone from the XIB when it compiles.

Comment: I presumed that the OP was asking about pre-compilation manipulation of XIBs, so the manipulated file would still be compiled down as normal.